# Java: When DLLs are loaded by a ClassLoader where are they stored in memory?

Tags: java, memory, dll, jvm, classloader

My understanding is that the `.dlls` are loaded into `java.library.path` by a `ClassLoader` but where are they stored in memory after `System.loadLibrary()` and `System.load()` is called from a non-static procedure?

[image: JVM Internal Architecture]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `System.loadLibrary()` or `System.load()` functions are called, the `ClassLoader` for the current Java class is tasked with finding the requested DLL (and its dependencies) and informing the operating system about the libraries' locations. The `ClassLoader` itself does not perform any loading: this operation uses the Java Native Interface (JNI) libraries to communicate with the operating system and tells it where to look for the requested libraries.

When a DLL function is called, the function is loaded into the *address space* of the Java VM process and is executed there. This address space is a memory block given to a process by the operating system and is *separate* from the Java VM altogether. So, the answer to your question is that the Java VM simply uses its given address space to load DLL functions on-demand and executes them through the Java Native Interface.

Source: http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/Tricks-of-the-Java-Programming-Gurus/ch30.htm

Comment: @Adil, your knowledge might help solving the problem which is stated here: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057895/system-load-generates-a-memory-failure-memmove-avx-unaligned-erms). The question relates to this answer: memory errors occurring when loading a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

'Non-static procedure' has nothing to do with it. Neither does the Java heap, and neither does Java, or your picture. The code is mapped into the process's code space and the data is mapped into the process's data space.

Comment: I am interested in learning more about the "process data space". Do you know of a picture representation or diagram of where the dlls are loaded? What else is loaded into this space? How are size limitations specified?

Comment: Every process in an operating system has code space and data space. Too broad to answer here.